# Is there a workaround for Django's `ModelDoesNotExist` error in a situation like this?

Tags: django, django-models

So I get a `ModelDoesNotExist` error when I run `manage.py runserver` because in a file in my directory, I make a query to a table which has not been populated yet.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.spotify_object = SocialToken.objects.get(account__provider="spotify")
```

The above is a class instantiated to perform some sort of authentication and the `SocialToken` table gets populated only after I login. Now, I was wondering if there was a way to escape the error by triggering this part of the code only after I login? I only use the class in an endpoint, and during that period, the table would have been populated but the fact that it is not populated before running the server is causing a `DoesNotExist` error. Is there a solution to this?

`Traceback`

```
File "C:\Users\Kwaku Biney\Desktop\sparison-1\project\Sparison\views.py", line 4, in <module>
from .authentication import SparisonCacheHandler
File "C:\Users\Kwaku Biney\Desktop\sparison-1\project\Sparison\authentication.py", line 43, in 
<module>
cache_handler = SparisonCacheHandler() ,
 File "C:\Users\Kwaku Biney\Desktop\sparison-1\project\Sparison\authentication.py", line 25, 
in __init__
self.spotify_object = SocialToken.objects.get(account__provider="spotify")
File "C:\Users\Kwaku Biney\Desktop\sparison-1\project\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Kwaku Biney\Desktop\sparison-1\project\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 429, in get
raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
allauth.socialaccount.models.DoesNotExist: SocialToken matching query does not exist.
```

In my `views.py`, I import the class which has the query and the error comes up.

Comment: You should be able to check `request.user.is_authenticated` to see if the current user is logged in or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to avoid the `DoesNotExist` Error.

A) Use `.filter()` instead of `.get()`
Filtering leads to an empty queryset when the search comes up empty.

```py
def __init__(self):
    self.spotify_object = SocialToken.objects.filter(account__provider="spotify")
```

B) Use `get_object_or_404()` instead of `.get()`
This is a built-in function by django:

> ```
> Calls get() on a given model manager, but it raises Http404 instead of the model’s DoesNotExist exception.
> ```

[Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404)

```py
def __init__(self):
    self.spotify_object = SocialToken.objects.get_object_or_404(account__provider="spotify")
```

Hope I could help you. Have a nice day.

Comment: Doesn't work. I think the Social Token table has to be created and that gets created only after logging in.

Comment: For some weird reason, I revisited this problem and this solution actually worked.